# Color time ranges in Outlook (2010) Calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, colors, calendar

In Microsoft Outlook 2010, I would like to color specific time ranges in the calendar. So for example, make the background of some days dark blue between 9:00 AM and 11:00 AM.

I know it's possible to put (empty) appointments recurring on those slots and have those have the right color. But what I want is for people to see the kind of appointments that can be scheduled at that time, so that there isn't an appointment there yet.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the closest you can get is setting the work week in settings -> calendar -> work week.

The time and days you set here will be colored differently in your own calendar (at least in the work week view) and this will be visible to others who view your calendar.

I don't know of any way of creating more than one category of "work week" and labeling them in the calendar, though.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this would be a huge improvement to Outlook.  Many efficiency experts recommend time blocking.  Using empty appointments to block the time is absolutely NOT the way to handle it, because the blocking appointments then actually conflict with the real appointments.  What you want is a way to show what kinds of appointments can be put in that block, so actually putting such an appointment in that time slot shouldn't create a conflict.

The Outlook developers plainly understand this approach to time blocking, because this is EXACTLY what they do with the "work hours"--the work hours are shaded one color, and the other hours a different color.  This approach simply needs to be given far, far more flexibility.

Comment: This answer pretty much duplicates the information in Glenruben Engen's answer, adding some commentary.  Super User is a knowledge base of solutions, so each answer is intended to provide a substantially different solution from what has already been contributed.  With a little more rep, you will be able to post comments, which would be a more appropriate way to add supplemental information like this.